# Please explain the operator of \rput command in the following code:

Tags: pstricks, pspicture

```
\begin{pspicture}
\psgrid[gridcolor=gray,subgridcolor=lightgray](0,0)(5,5)
\rput[bl](0,1){bottom left (0,1)}
\rput[tr](5,1){top right (5,1)}
\rput[t](2,2){stuff1}
\end{pspicture}
```

I think it :

[image]

Comment: Where can we find definitions for `\rputbl`, `\rputtr` and `\rputt`?

Comment: I have read \rput 's turtorial in Pstrick user's guide but i don't think result of its code as such.

Comment: Editted code. sorry

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The optional argument for `\rput[<refpoint>](x,y){<stuff>}` provides the `ref`erence `point` (or anchor) for `<stuff>`. So, using `\rput[tl](x,y){<stuff>}` puts the `t`op `l`eft corner of `<stuff>` at `(x,y)`. Similarly for `\rput[bl]` and `\rput[t]` (and any of the possible combinations listed in the [`pstricks`](//ctan.org/pkg/pstricks) [documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/graphics/pstricks/base/doc/pstricks-doc.pdf).

[image]

Comment: ""So, using \rput[tl](x,y){<stuff>} puts the top left corner of <stuff> at  (x,y) """ in your answer. It is the key to my question. Again, thanks a lot

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid,framesep=0pt](6,3)
\psdots(0,1)(5,1)(2,2)
\rput[bl](0,1){\psframebox{bottom left (0,1)}}
\rput[tr](5,1){\psframebox{top right (5,1)}}
\rput[t](2,2){\psframebox{stuff1}}
\end{pspicture}

\bigskip
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid,framesep=0pt](6,3)
\psdots(0,1)(5,1)(2,2)
\uput{0}[45](0,1){\psframebox{bottom left (0,1)}}
\uput{0}[-135](5,1){\psframebox{top right (5,1)}}
\uput{0}[-90](2,2){\psframebox{stuff1}}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In the following example we need '\rput` to put stuff centered to a point:

```
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid,framesep=0pt](5,5)
\psdots(2.5,2.5)
\multido{\iA=0+10}{36}{\uput{10mm}[\iA](2.5,2.5){\psframebox{some text}}}
\rput(2.5,2.5){Center}
\end{pspicture}
```

[image]

Comment: \rput[bl]=\uput{0}[45],\rput[tr]=\uput{0}[-135],\rput[t]=\uput{0}[-90]. They are equivalent. So, in your opinion, which should be used? :((

Comment: They _can_ be the same! With `\uput`  you can rotate the label around the given point. However, it depends on what you want. A label right beside is easier with `\uput[0](x,y){foo}'

Comment: As my think, "bottom left" is must be {0}[-135].... I want to know  my think is not right or Pstricks code is wrong! according to book , "bl" lie that position! :((

Comment: again: `\rput` and `\uput` _can_ be the same but only for the positions which `\rput` allows (see image on Werners answer). With `\uput` you can place it at _any_ angle, e.g. 100, which is not possible with `\rput`

Comment: :((, so i will choose \uput for my code in the future. Thank you a lots for your answer.

Comment: I'll add an example, wait a minute

Comment: Yes, ""So, using \rput[tl](x,y){<stuff>} puts the top left corner of <stuff> at  (x,y)"" in Werner's answer is the key to my question.. And you, who added information about \rput command to me. :-))

Answer (score 1):

## Warning!

The `refpoint` optional argument only works for "boxed" objects as follows.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=1cm]{standalone}

\def\unboxedObject{\psframe(2,1)}
\def\boxedObject{\psframebox{\Huge \"Age}}

\begin{document}    
\foreach \i in{t,tl,l,bl,b,br,r,tr,t,Bl,B,Br}{%
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid,dimen=m](4,3)
    \rput[b](2,0.1){\bf \i} 
    \rput[\i](2,2){\boxedObject}
    %\rput[\i](2,2){\unboxedObject}
    \pscircle*[linecolor=red](2,2){2pt}
\end{pspicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For "unboxed" objects, the argument `refpoint` does not affect. The terminologies "boxed" and "unboxed" used here have nothing to do with the same terms used in C# or Java programming languages.

Comment: It works for "boxes"! `\psframe` alone is not a box! inside `pspicture` environment it is like a box.

Comment: If we replace "\rput" as "\Rput (an obsolete command)" ,the refpoint optional argument works normally without \psframebox. Is that true?? :-) (in Pstricks User’s Guide p.45)

Comment: @TrongVuong: I don't use `\Rput` so I don't know its behavior. :-)

Comment: I have also just known ! :-)) (My english not so good, i usualy use google translate) :))